# How can one manually set boot options to boot from a particular partition?

Tags: linux, boot

I got a new PC a few days ago, and I installed on it Linux Mint, my OS of choice. There were a few bugs with wireless connectivity and battery management, so I thought that perhaps updating my computer's BIOS might solve the problems.

After updating my BIOS in Windows, my computer now boots by default to Windows instead of pulling up GRUB so that I can access Mint. I went to my boot options to manually select where to boot from, but instead of saying the usual boot options (Should be Windows boot manager and something along the lines of linux-mint with the version number), my boot options are now "ubuntu" and "Windows boot manager". Upon running "ubuntu", Windows boots up. I can't find any way to access my linux partition at all.

After assessing the situation a little, I've found that my Mint partition is still intact, but I have no way to access it. How could I manually edit my boot setting to boot from this partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can boot a live disk and reinstall grub. For example you could use [the super grub disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) or any other live disk. You may need to boot into "rescue mode" in order to get a command line to reinstall grub. When you get a shell, you can issue the commands to reinstall grub. For example [for Mint.](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/245)